# Why stream.size always longer than the length of string

Tags: wpf, stream

I have a textblock and there're some text in it. When I convert the string in the textblock to stream, the stream.size always longer than textblock.text.length, why? Always have 4 characters longer.

Comment: To what stream are you converting it? Please show your code, as there exists no `Size` property on [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream).

Comment: Could it be encoding data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my test, and the results:

In XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtbx" Text="Four" />
```

In C#:

```
int txt = txtbx.Text.Length;
long streamLength = 0;
using (Stream test = new MemoryStream())
{
    test.Write(txtbx.Text.Select(t => (byte)(int)t).ToArray(), 0, txtbx.Text.Length);
    streamLength = test.Length;
}
// Result: txt = 4
//        streamLength = 4
```

So my answer is: either you have encoding issues, or you made the stream wrong. And if I was to take a guess, you messed with the last 2 arguments of Stream.Write .